# Rig in which + distributes over *

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a commutative rig (ring without additive inverses). Suppose that addition in $A$ distributes over multiplication in $A$, so that $A$ is a rig in $2$ ways, depending on which operation we think of as the multiplication.

> **Question:** Are all such rigs distributive lattices?

This question is interesting to me because it contends to show a special property of distributive lattices: that they are precisely the sets with $2$ commutative monoidal operations which distribute over each other.

Note that it suffices to show that $\forall a \in A : a^2 = a$ and $\forall a \in A : a +a =a$.

**Edit:** One answer has shown that without a unit for $+$ and $\cdot$, my note above does not hold, and the answer is also false. I should have stated which meaning of "lattice" I am using, namely that a lattice is a poset with finite meets and joins, including the empty meet and empty join.

Comment: Do we assume $A$ is commutative under both $+$ and $\cdot$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath yes!

Comment: Perhaps I am simply uneducated in matters of rigs, but when I hear distributive, I think $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. This is not what's in the accepted answer: it says $a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)$. What's going on here?

Comment: @HankScorpio Good question, Hank. Your first axiom is $a(b+c) = ab + ac$, and this is true in every rig. However, this question specifies something extra that is not true of all rigs: "Suppose that addition in $A$ distributes...". What that means is that $a + bc = (a+b)(a+c)$, and this is the second equation you have written. In this way, both of the equations you have written are assumed here.

Comment: So the sentence "addition in $A$ distributes over multiplication" is the assumption $a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)$. Huh. I have never heard of this before - where do people talk about such things? Any attempt to google "distributes over" only brings up examples of the typical distributive property.

Comment: @HankScorpio The subject would be called "universal algebra", and a keyword is "variety" (but don't confuse that variety with the variety in algebraic geometry). This distributive property is really rare, though. As the problem shows, if two monoidal operations distribute over each other, then we have a distributive lattice.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and the pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distributivity of addition over multiplication says $$a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)$$ for any $a,b,c$.  Setting $b=c=0$ gives $a=a^2$.  Setting $b=0$ and $c=1$ gives $a=a(a+1)=a^2+a=a+a$.

(Alternatively, assuming that by "addition distributing over multiplication" you include the case of nullary multiplication where it says $a+1=1$, then you can deduce $a=a+a$ by just dualizing the argument for $a=a^2$.  Actually, though, that nullary case does not have to be assumed, since it follows automatically.  Indeed, setting $a=1$ and $c=0$ in $a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)$ gives $1=(1+b)1=1+b$ for arbitrary $b$.)

Comment: Thanks Eric. You always give the best answers!