# Is there a field (or field-like structure) that is distributive over both operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Is there a field (or field-like structure) that is distributive over both operations?

i.e. $(F,+,*)$ such that $\forall a,b,c \in F  $

1. $a+(b*c) = (a+b)*(a+c) $
2. $a*(b+c) = (a*b)+(a*c)$

P.S.: For example, conjuction and disjunction both satisfy these properties.

P.S.S:
Field axioms:

1. $(F,+)$ is an abelian group.
2. Multiplication is associative
3. $\exists 1\in F$ such that $\forall a\in F$, $a*1 = 1*a$.
4. $\forall a\in F$, if $a\neq 0$ then there exists $b\in F$ such that $a*b=b*a = 1$.
5. Multiplication is distributive over addition

Comment: Do you require $(F,+)$ to be an abelian group? Or do you just have "two binary operations that distribute over each other" and no other conditions?  What *exactly* do you want your operations to satisfy? See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171381/rig-in-which-distributes-over)

Comment: I want it to satisfy as many axioms of a field as possible. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Can you list what the axioms are, according to you? There are several equivalent ways to define a field.

Comment: Put it in the **post**, not buried in comments.

Comment: Greetings!  I have taken the liberty to use your question as the post title. I did this because "question about a <general term>" is a great way to make sure people ignore your question.  In the future, just do your best to use the question as the title. Regards

Comment: Your axiom 4 was wrong; you need to exclude $a=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $(F,+,*)$ is a structure in which $(F,+)$ is an abelian group with identity $0$, $(F,*)$ is a commutative monoid with identity $1$ (your axioms 1, 2, and 3); $*$ distributes over $+$ (your axiom 5); *and* $+$ distributes over $*$, then you just get a structure with a single element $\{0\}$. We don't even need multiplicative inverses.

Indeed, first, note that $a*0 = 0$ for all $a$, since $a*0 = a*(0+0) = (a*0)+(a*0)$, and cancelling we get $a*0 = 0$.

Next, note that $a^2=a$ for all $a$. Indeed, since $+$ distributes over $*$, we have
$$a = a+0 = a+(0*0) = (a+0)*(a+0) = a*a = a^2.$$

And if $1$ is the identity element of $*$, then since $+$ distributes over $*$  and $*$ distributes over $+$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
a &= a+0\\
 &= a+(1*0)\\
 &= (a+1)*(a+0)\\
 &= (a+1)*a \\
&= a^2+(1*a)\\
&=a^2+a\\
&=a+a.
\end{align*}$$

But then, because $(F,+)$ is an abelian group, we can cancel $a$ from $a=a+a$ to get $a=0$.